# Managing Multiple Bases in a Minecraft Faction

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On a Factions Minecraft server, I'm planning to build more than one base, so that I have a backup place in case one of them gets raided. I know that I can use /sethome on one base, and /f sethome on another, but I want to to make more than only two bases.

What's the best way to quickly travel between three or more bases so that no two bases have a connection?

- This is a Bukkit Server, and I'm allowed to have one /home.
- I'm planning on living as a hermit.

Answer (score 2):

So there is many steps to take when going about this,  but as long as you claim that third base; it should be effective, here they are:

**Create a transport system between the bases:**

You can find some other players who are willing to help you if you want, but creating three bases and having a very well organized transport system that goes through all three would be a good place to start. Create an underground system, of track that takes you in and out of each base; especially if you plan on building a large city.

**Organize each base:**

A good place to start when maintaining these bases is to have specific things in each of them. For instance, one base has building plots and homes. Another base sells weapons, armor, redstone, blocks; you name it. The third base can be something like where you farm your wheat, and have nether portals and mob spawners.

**Have a centre, or hub**

I know it's factions, not towny. However, having a nice center town area where members of your base could potentially trade each other items. Whatever, but a good center place is a good place to branch your bases from.

**Build your bases strategically**

You claim you are gonna be a hermit, so I suppose that means your gonna be more on the defensive than offensive side. Build your bases at places away from enemies and closer to allies.

Find a place where a lot of people come across, as well; so you have more people to recruit to your faction.

**Tips:**

- Just because your base is organized, doesn't mean it's fancy. You don't need gothic cathedrals; just designated space, even underground to build each of your basis. With the exception of the houses, considering you want them to look nice.
- Maintaining bases can be difficult if you're trying to prevent being raided by someone else. You have more space to help protect. Try to have good pvpers that belong to each of the bases in case of a raid by your adverseries.

**Final Word:**

This is just my silly opinion, so take it with a pinch of salt. That's just what I would do. If you agree and find it works for you, amazing. If not, well then don't take this post too seriously.

Comment: Yeah, there doesn't seem to be much more that you could do, unless you dynamically set your home (which would be pretty much impossible). +1

Comment: Read my updated post.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, but the main point is so that no bases have any connection with each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 1 allowed home on the server then dont bother with a second. Instead use the resources on redstone traps and you wont need a second home.

Comment: Similarly, you could always hold a hard drive on you and never let it touch anything, but it could still fail. Back ups are _always_ good, and it is specifically what the OP is asking for. As such, this does not answer the question.